# How to store tree structure in python permanently

Tags: python, tree, store, permanent

I created a **tree structure** using **python**. Assume the tree has root node, left and right child. I need to acceess the tree whenever required. But on opening the file and running makes recreation of tree. As i have huge number of nodes in tree, so the method of recreation is time consuming. Please provide me a solution such that **i can store the tree, fetch and update(insert or delete a node) whenever required.**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is to broad and lacks of informations and a minimal working example. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help and read there to find out how to ask questions.
Beside this maybe the `json` module could be your friend. I solve similiar task with it.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module that can be used to serialize and deserialize python objects quite easily.

```
import pickle

tree = {'a': 'b'}
# serializing the data
with open('/path/to/some/file', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(tree, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# and deserializing it again
with open('/path/to/same/file', 'rb') as f:
    tree = pickle.load(f)
```